# How to make labels non-italicized in tikz-cd?

Tags: labels, tikz-cd

I have the following LaTeX code:

```
\tikzcdset{every label/.append style={font=\normalfont\scriptsize}}

$$
\begin{tikzcd}
G\arrow[r, "\alpha"] \arrow[d, "{onto}"] & G'\\
 G/N\arrow[r, "\cong"] & I \arrow[u, "{inj.}"']\\
\end{tikzcd}.
$$
```

This gives me this:

[image]

All I want to do is make the labels "onto" and "inj." in text font, not math font.  That is, I want the tags not italicized.

Comment: Use `\text{onto}`

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Can you please -- as usual here -- make your code snippet be compilable? Then we do not have to guess what you are doing ...

Answer (score 1):

Here there is a MWE. From by comment of the very nice user *@Sigur* ...using `\textup{}` as alternative...and never to use double dollar `$$...$$` in `LaTeX`: [Why is \[ ... \] preferable to $$ ... $$?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/503/why-is-preferable-to)

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
\tikzcdset{every label/.append style={font=\normalfont\scriptsize}}
\[\begin{tikzcd}
G\arrow[r, "\alpha"] \arrow[d, "\textup{onto}"] & G'\\
G/N\arrow[r, "\cong"] & I \arrow[u, "\textup{inj.}"']
\end{tikzcd}.\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Commutative are always in math environment, so if you like to have sin it some normal text, you should use `\text` command (as mentioned @Sigur in his comment) provided by `amsmath` package:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm, varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
    \[
\begin{tikzcd}
G\arrow[r, "\alpha"] \arrow[d, "\text{onto}"] & G'\\
 G/N\arrow[r, "\cong"] & I \arrow[u, "\text{inj.}"']\\
\end{tikzcd}
    \]
\end{document}
```

Please observe of use `\[` and `\]` instead `$$`, which are TeX command, not LaTeX.

[image]